# Mapeamento entre FHIR e OpenEHR

Tags: map

Estou com uma dúvida sobre mapeamento entre modelos de persistência  e interoperabilidade de dados de saúde.

Existe algum mapeamento entre FHIR e OpenEHR? Se sim, como deve ser feito? Há alguma forma automática de fazê-lo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou estudando o assunto também, e ao que me parece não existe uma forma automática de fazê-lo.

O FHIR e o OpenEHR já provém algumas estruturas similares, porém, não há um mapeamento 100% direto entre as estruturas, onde haja uma relação perfeita.

O que está indicado neste site [link](https://wolandscat.net/2018/10/10/fhir-v-openehr-concreta/) é que pode-se utilizar *Profiles* e *Extensions* do FHIR como auxiliadores para o mapeamento entre as abstrações.

Você pode acompanhar a thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036276/is-reversible-mapping-between-fhir-and-archetypes-possible), que indica também que ainda não há esse mapeamento.

Espero ter ajudado,
Abraços